# Error while starting a workflow in sensenet (Basic workflow)

Tags: sensenet

I was trying to enable/configure basic workflow in sensenet back-end application. I performed the following steps and I am getting the error mentioned below.

Steps performed

- I had enabled approval for one document library (Home / workspaces / Document Workspaces / London Document Workspace / Document library) in Sensenet demo server
- I assigned workflow for approval and checked all 4 available options for initiating workflow
- I created a new content and while uploading (all workflows were set to automatically execute), I got the following error

> The following errors were encountered while processing the workflow tree:\n DynamicActivity : The private implementation of activity 1: DynamicActivity has the following validation error: Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression CType(StateContent( Workspace ), SenseNet.ContentRepository.GenericContent).Path & /Tasks .\nReference required to assembly netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51 containing the base class System.Object . Add one to your project.\n

How can I rectify this?

Comment: This is probably caused by a missing reference/using line in the xaml file that defines the workflow (they are old, way older than netstandard). We'll check that and see if it can be solved by simply modifying the xaml.

Comment: Hi.Any solution found out for this error?